# Login with an existing google account in Apple Mail using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, google-signin, apple-mail

Purpose: Automation

Tool: AppleScript

Email Client: Apple Mail

OS: macOS Big Sur Version 11.4

I have an existing google account. I need to login to the Apple Mail app using this google account using AppleScript. Is there any way I can achieve this?

I have tried the below code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set smtpServerName to "smtp.gmail.com"
    set addsmtp to make new smtp server with properties {server name:smtpServerName}
    tell addsmtp
        set authentication to kerberos 5
        set password to thePassword
        set uses ssl to true
        set port to 25
        set user name to theUserName
    end tell

    set theNewAccount to make new imap account with properties {name:theAccountName, user name:theUserName, server name:"imap.gmail.com", password:thePassword, full name:theFullName, email addresses:{theUserName & "@gmail.com"}, port:143, uses ssl:true, enabled:true, authentication:kerberos 5, store junk mail on server:false, empty sent messages frequency:-1, empty junk messages on quit:true, empty trash frequency:30, store deleted messages on server:true, empty sent messages on quit:true, smtp server:smtp server "smtp.gmail.com" of application "Mail", empty trash on quit:false, compact mailboxes when closing:true, store sent messages on server:true, move deleted messages to trash:true, include when getting new mail:true, class:imap account, empty junk messages frequency:30, store drafts on server:false, message caching:all messages and their attachments}
    set smtp server of account theAccountName to smtp server "smtp.gmail.com"
end tell
```

While running this code, I am getting this error:

```
error "Mail got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

What is wrong in the code? Or is there any other way I can login with existing google account in Apple Mail using AppleScript?

Comment: The main mistake I see is that you are trying to authenticate using both a **password** and the **kerberos 5** protocol. Also, setting these properties before creating the account itself does not make sense. Since these properties **belong to the account**, and not to the application (like yours). You should firstly create new account using minimal set of its properties (**name, user name, server name, password, full name, email addresses**}. Then you can set its additional properties telling to this created account.

Answer (score 0):

```
property accountName : "KniazidisR_11"
property emailUsername : "KniazidisR"
property theHostname : "mail.example.com"
property emailAddresses : {"kniazidis.robert@gmail.com", "kniazidis2.robert2@gmail.com"}
property theFullName : "Robert Kniazidis"
property passwordConstant : «constant exutaxct» -- ADDED

-- following is better to be secret
set emailPassword to text returned of (display dialog "Enter email password" default answer "" with hidden answer)

tell application "Mail"
    set p to it
    set newAccount to make new imap account with properties {name:accountName, user name:emailUsername, server name:theHostname, password:emailPassword, full name:theFullName, email addresses:emailAddresses}
    tell newAccount
        -- following code line is EDITED as well
        set authentication to passwordConstant -- or,   to kerberos 5,    or ....
        set port to 25
        -- set other properties
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you Robert Kniazidis. Let me try the way you suggested. As you mentioned, I'll login firstm then set the additional properties.

Comment: Hey @robert-kniazidis, Thank you again for the script. While running the above snippet, why I am getting this error:

`Mail got an error: Can’t make password of account id "<account_id>" into type constant.`

Comment: Hey, @Ajith Kumar. The error was because **password property** of account conflicts  with **password constant**. I updated my answer to fix this Mail.app issue.

Comment: How did you come up with the passwordConstant @RobertKniazidis ?

Comment: RE: @AhiyaHiya: using Script Debugger with Show Raw (Chevron) Syntax